# Deluge in Hinduism - some clarifications needed

Tags: yuga, time, manu, cosmology, manvantara

Trying to understand [the great deluge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shraddhadeva_Manu#The_Great_Deluge) in Hinduism, I am in need of some clarifications. Do not assume any prior knowledge.

1. When did this great deluge exactly happen according to Hindu scriptures?
2. Are deluge and world destruction at each kalpa period two different events or one and the same? Or was the deluge just one time event so it's something unrelated to world destruction at the end of kalpa cycle? In this case how are the Manvantara divided? What happens with world as we know it at the end of each Manu period that demands creation of a new Manu?
3. According to some sources each Manu is created by supreme deity itself, but, as it appears in some sources, the 7<sup>th</sup> Manu was a king with well defined ancestors, and of course the rishis were already with him to save, how come?

Comment: welcome to Hinduism SE. I think each of your question deserves a broader discussion. It would be difficult to fit all the answers in one.

Comment: I think you could ask each question separately